# How to read information in text file in order to plot the data ? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm beginning in matlab and I'm searching how to get the information that are written in a .txt file (that would be in this format :

```
% t, x1, x2
0 1 1
0.01 1.01902 1.0195
0.02 1.03706 1.0376
0.03 1.05411 1.0511
0.04 1.07019 1.0719
0.05 1.08529 1.0829
0.06 1.0994 1.094
0.07 1.11253 1.1153
0.08 1.12468 1.128
0.09 1.13586 1.136
0.1 1.14604 1.14615
```

in order to then plot them in different figures using matlab. The program has to check how many columns are written (here 1 + 2 ), take the first one for the abscises, and the next ones for ploting the y-axis. The columns are separated with one blank ( " " ).

My problem is that I don't know how to know how many columns there is, and then do the for-loop.  I'm interested in knowing how to plot everything on one screen and on different screens for each column.

by now i ve done this :

```
 data = load('test.txt');

t  = data(:, 1);
ta = data(:, 2);

x = 0: pi/10: pi;
y = sin(x)/ 100 +1;


figure('Name','Name Hello1','NumberTitle','off', ...
'units','normalized','outerposition',[0.01 0.1 0.5 0.7]);
h1 = figure(1);
plot(t, ta, 'bx', 'LineWidth',2)
title('2-D Line Plot')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('cos(5x)')

figure('Name','Name hello 2 2','NumberTitle','off',...
'units','normalized','outerposition',[0.02 0.07 0.5 0.7]);
h2 = figure(2);
plot(x, y , 'LineWidth',2)
title('2-D Line Plot')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('cos(5x)')
```

Comment: You want the program to figure out how many columns there are on it's own? so it's not always 3 columns? Can you show us what you tried so far pls?

Comment: no it can be 2 or 3 or 4 or even 10. I ve not tried anything, I have already been struggling 2 hours to understand how to plot a function hahah but I can add my results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use low level routines like `fopen` and `textscan` to read regular data like this, especially if you don't know how many columns there are.  Nor to use a loop to plot the data, unless you really want them to be on separate figures, which for this data would seem unusual

Use `readtable` to read the file, and plot all the columns in the same axis:

```
data = readtable('test.txt');
plot(data{:,1},data{:,2:end});
```

Or if you do want separate figures:

```
for idx = 1:width(data)-1
   figure(idx)
   plot(data{:,1},data{:,idx+1});
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can plot everything in one window using this:

```
fid=fopen('test.txt'); % opening the file
dataPlain=textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter',''); % reading the data from the file
data=cellfun(@str2num,dataPlain{1},'uni',0); % getting only the numerical data
data=cat(1,data{:}); % formatting
figure; % if you want to plot everything in multiple windows, you can put this command into the for loop, too.
hold on
for ii=2:size(data,2)
    plot(data(:,1),data(:,ii)); % plot the data
end
```

Comment: there is one problem for multiple windows, one window appears with nothing on it

Comment: doesn't happen for me. Where did you put the `figure`-command? It needs to come BEFORE the plot command.

Comment: yes it's what i ve done. It is not that important so thank you anyway :)